# $A=PBQ$, where $P,~Q$ invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A,~B\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ such that $A=PBQ$ for some invertible matrix $P,~Q$.

How to prove that $A$ has a left inverse if and only if $\text{rank}(B)=n$?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the proof but may be the proof goes like this : If $A$ has a left inverse say($C$) then $I=CA=CPBQ$ and hence $B$ has to be of rank $n$(else rank of $CPBQ\ne n$) and for the converse if $B$ has rank $n$ then $B$ is invertible and hence $A$ will be invertible.