# $A=PBQ$, the relation between $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A,~B\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ such that $A=PBQ$ for some invertible matrix $P,~Q$.

How to prove that "$\forall b\in \Bbb R^m,~Bx=b$ has a solution" if and only if $\text{nullity}A=n-m$? I think the statement is true, and I have test in by Mathematica. However, it's hard for me to figure out a proof!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2441742/328173)

Comment: Can't see the relation.

Comment: Same author, same first sentence, same background...

Comment: Yes. Since I sometimes heard people say different question should ask in different post.. Should I merge them?

Comment: I didn't say you should merge them. If so, I would have said "duplicate" instead.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm{nullity}(A) = n-m$?

Comment: @MarcusM Yes, $n-m$. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:  Show that (under the condition $A = PBQ$ for $P$ and $Q$ invertible) $$\forall b \in \mathbb{R}^m,~Bx = b~\text{has a solution} \iff \forall a \in \mathbb{R}^m,~Ax = a~\text{has a solution}. $$

Then try to prove the following equivalence $$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^m,~Ax = a~\text{has a solution} \iff \mathrm{nullity}(A) = n-m.$$

Does this remind you of any theorem from linear algebra?